# Gradation color in WebGL with GLSL shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I would have black color in the middle of my disk with a gradation from the outside.
the 2 first parts are the GLSL code to make my shader, my problem is when i do :  "gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( vUv, 0.17 ), 1. ); "

`

```
varying vec2 vUv;

    void main()
    {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 0.8);
    }
```

'
'

```
varying vec2 vUv;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( vUv, 0.17 ), 1. );
}
```

'

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 1024 / 860, 0.1, 1000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});

camera.position.z = 30;
var my_shad = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertex' ).textContent,
fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'frag' ).textContent
});

var radius = 8;
var segments = 80;
var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );              
var disk = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, my_shad);
scene.add(disk);

renderer.setSize( 1024, 860 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

'

Comment: Please formulate your question better. There is no question here.

Comment: Agreed. 

What is vec3(vUv, 0.17) supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this for starters:

```
void main(){
float uvD = length(vUv);
vec3 gradient = mix(color1, color2, uvD);
gl_FragColor = vec4(gradient,1.);
}
```